# pyqtdeploy: qt license file not found

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqtdeploy

I'm trying to work my way through the [pyqtdeploy documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/), trying to build the [pyqt-demo project](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/demo.html).

My system is an Ubuntu 18.04 (fresh installation, up-to-date)

```
$ uname -a :
Linux sui 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using pyqtdeploy v. 2.3.

I downloaded every file required by the build(*) but I have a problem with the Qt tarball : I downloaded https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1.tar.xz, not knowing if it was the right file to be used.

... and this is what I got:

```
$ python3 build-demo.py --verbose --source-dir=[skipped] --installed-qt-dir=[skipped]

[skipped]Creating qmake...
Done.
Info: creating super cache file [skipped]/sysroot-linux-64/build/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/.qmake.super
Info: creating stash file [skipped]/demo/sysroot-linux-64/build/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/.qmake.stash

Error: Qt license file was not found!
Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

ERROR: You are not licensed to use this software.
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Execution failed: returned exit code 3
```

I'm 100% sure the qt-*.tar.xz file is found since an message appears, saying that the file is unpacked.

I'm obviously missing something important : should I use a file like qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.11.1.tar.xz [although I can't find such a file](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&hl=fr&ei=zQz3W5v9LIOma_2or7gN&q=%22qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.11.1.tar.xz%22&oq=%22qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.11.1.tar.xz%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...13490.13918.0.14255.2.2.0.0.0.0.162.251.1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.-DNcBcIM64k) ?
Any help would be appreciated !

---

(*) [required tarballs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/demo.html):

- python  : https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tar.xz
  at https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/
- qt      : https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1.tar.xz at https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.11/5.11.1/single/
- openssl : https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz at
  https://www.openssl.org/source/
- zlib    : https://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz at https://zlib.net/
- sip     : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.19.13/sip-4.19.13.tar.gz at https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download
- PyQt5   : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.11.3/PyQt5_gpl-5.11.3.tar.gz at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5
- PyQt3D  : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt3D/PyQt3D-5.11.3/PyQt3D_gpl-5.11.3.tar.gz at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt3d/download
- PyQtChart : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQtChart/PyQtChart-5.11.3/PyQtChart_gpl-5.11.3.tar.gz at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtchart/download
- PyQtDataVisualization : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQtDataVisualization/PyQtDataVisualization-5.11.3/PyQtDataVisualization_gpl-5.11.3.tar.gz at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdatavisualization/download
- PyQtPurchasing : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQtPurchasing/PyQtPurchasing-5.11.3/PyQtPurchasing_gpl-5.11.3.tar.gz at
  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtpurchasing/download
- QScintilla : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/QScintilla2/QScintilla-2.10.8/QScintilla_gpl-2.10.8.tar.gz at https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/download

Answer (score 1):

Fixed since pyqtdeploy-2.3.1.dev1811241346. See [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/pyqtdemo-build-qt-license-file-not-found-td5243878.html) for Phil Thomson's answer and [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdeploy/download) to download the last snapshot.